# xml.unmarshal not traversing the XML Tree

Tags: xml, go, marshalling

I am attempting to marshal XML over to a set of custom structs and it isn't working as I would expect.  I would expect that the xml.StartElement for each of my "UnmarshalXML" functions would change for each object that it is processing (e.g. TrainingCenterDatabase vs Activities).   That doesn't appear to be happening.   My xml.StartElement is always the root element of the entire XML File.

In addition, my final decoded Struct is empty when the Unmarshaling is completed.   I hypothesize that because the wrong "startElement" is being passed in then it isn't finding any values to parse.

What am I doing wrong?

Structs and Functions:

```
func (v *TrainingCenterDatabase) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, startElement xml.StartElement) error {
    decodeError := d.DecodeElement(&v.Activities, &startElement)
    fmt.Println("TrainingCenterDatabase StartELement Name: " + startElement.Name.Local)
    if decodeError != nil {
        logging.LogError("tcxhelper - XMLTpxFile.UnmarshalXML Error - "+decodeError.Error(), "")
        return decodeError
    }
    return nil
}

func (v *Activities) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, startElement xml.StartElement) error {
    decodeError := d.DecodeElement(&v.Activity, &startElement)
    fmt.Println("Activities StartELement Name: " + startElement.Name.Local)
    if decodeError != nil {
        logging.LogError("tcxhelper - XMLTpxFile.UnmarshalXML Error - "+decodeError.Error(), "")
        return decodeError
    }
    return nil
}

func (v *Activity) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, startElement xml.StartElement) error {
    for _, attr := range startElement.Attr {
        fmt.Println("Attr Name: " + attr.Name.Local)
        fmt.Println("Attr Value: " + attr.Value)
    }
    fmt.Println("Activity StartELement Name: " + startElement.Name.Local)

    decodeError := d.DecodeElement(&v.Lap, &startElement)
    if decodeError != nil {
        logging.LogError("tcxhelper - XMLTpxFile.UnmarshalXML Error - "+decodeError.Error(), "")
        return decodeError
    }
    return nil
}

type TpxFile struct {
    TpxFile TrainingCenterDatabase `xml:"TrainingCenterDatabase"`
}

type TrainingCenterDatabase struct {
    Activities Activities `xml:"Activities"`
}

type Activities struct {
    Activity Activity `xml:"Activity"`
}

type Activity struct {
    Sport string    `xml:"Sport"`
    ID    time.Time `xml:"Id"`
    Lap   Lap       `xml:"Lap"`
}

type Lap struct {
    Cadence       string `xml:"Cadence"`
    TriggerMethod string `xml:"TriggerMethod"`
    Track         Track  `xml:"Track"`
}

type Track struct {
    Trackpoint          Trackpoint          `xml:"Trackpoint"`
    MaximumSpeed        string              `xml:"MaximumSpeed"`
    MaximumHeartRateBpm MaximumHeartRateBpm `xml:"MaximumHeartRateBpm"`
    Intensity           string              `xml:"Intensity"`
    Calories            string              `xml:"Calories"`
    AverageHeartRateBpm AverageHeartRateBpm `xml:"AverageHeartRateBpm"`
    StartTime           time.Time           `xml:"StartTime"`
    TotalTimeSeconds    string              `xml:"TotalTimeSeconds"`
    DistanceMeters      string              `xml:"DistanceMeters"`
}

type MaximumHeartRateBpm struct {
    Value string `xml:"Value"`
}

type AverageHeartRateBpm struct {
    Value string `xml:"Value"`
}

type Trackpoint []struct {
    Position       Position     `xml:"Position"`
    AltitudeMeters string       `xml:"AltitudeMeters"`
    DistanceMeters string       `xml:"DistanceMeters"`
    HeartRateBpm   HeartRateBpm `xml:"HeartRateBpm"`
    Cadence        string       `xml:"Cadence"`
    Extensions     Extensions   `xml:"Extensions"`
    Time           time.Time    `xml:"Time"`
}

type Extensions struct {
    TPX TPX `xml:"TPX"`
}

type TPX struct {
    Xmlns string `xml:"xmlns"`
    Speed string `xml:"Speed"`
    Watts string `xml:"Watts"`
}
type HeartRateBpm struct {
    Value string `xml:"Value"`
}

type Position struct {
    LatitudeDegrees  string `xml:"LatitudeDegrees"`
    LongitudeDegrees string `xml:"LongitudeDegrees"`
}
```

Code to Marshal

```
func TestMarshalTPX(t *testing.T) {

    fileByteArray, myErr := ioutil.ReadFile("/my/local/directory/Lunch_Ride.tcx")
    if myErr != nil {
        t.Error("Error Reading File: " + myErr.Error())
    }
    tpxFile := TrainingCenterDatabase{}

    marshalError := xml.Unmarshal(fileByteArray, &tpxFile)
    if marshalError != nil {
        t.Error("Marshal Error: " + marshalError.Error())
    }
}
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TrainingCenterDatabase
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabasev2.xsd"
  xmlns:ns5="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityGoals/v1"
  xmlns:ns3="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2"
  xmlns:ns2="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/UserProfile/v2"
  xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Activities>
  <Activity Sport="Biking">
   <Id>2018-10-16T18:41:12Z</Id>
   <Lap StartTime="2018-10-16T18:41:12Z">
    <TotalTimeSeconds>3732</TotalTimeSeconds>
    <DistanceMeters>26451.5</DistanceMeters>
    <MaximumSpeed>52560.0</MaximumSpeed>
    <Calories>0</Calories>
    <AverageHeartRateBpm>
     <Value>148</Value>
    </AverageHeartRateBpm>
    <MaximumHeartRateBpm>
     <Value>188</Value>
    </MaximumHeartRateBpm>
    <Intensity>Active</Intensity>
    <Cadence>79</Cadence>
    <TriggerMethod>Manual</TriggerMethod>
    <Track>
     <Trackpoint>
      <Time>2018-10-16T18:41:12Z</Time>
      <Position>
       <LatitudeDegrees>39.7711140</LatitudeDegrees>
       <LongitudeDegrees>-105.0392580</LongitudeDegrees>
      </Position>
      <AltitudeMeters>1646.2</AltitudeMeters>
      <DistanceMeters>0.0</DistanceMeters>
      <HeartRateBpm>
       <Value>97</Value>
      </HeartRateBpm>
      <Cadence>69</Cadence>
      <Extensions>
       <TPX xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2">
        <Speed>0.0</Speed>
        <Watts>320</Watts>
       </TPX>
      </Extensions>
     </Trackpoint>
     <Trackpoint>
      <Time>2018-10-16T18:41:13Z</Time>
      <Position>
       <LatitudeDegrees>39.7711120</LatitudeDegrees>
       <LongitudeDegrees>-105.0392590</LongitudeDegrees>
      </Position>
      <AltitudeMeters>1646.2</AltitudeMeters>
      <DistanceMeters>0.2</DistanceMeters>
      <HeartRateBpm>
       <Value>97</Value>
      </HeartRateBpm>
      <Cadence>73</Cadence>
      <Extensions>
       <TPX xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2">
        <Speed>0.2</Speed>
        <Watts>195</Watts>
       </TPX>
      </Extensions>
     </Trackpoint>
    </Track>
   </Lap>
  </Activity>
 </Activities>
</TrainingCenterDatabase>
```

Comment: Have you tried without the custom unmarshal methods? It seems to unmarshal the data, altough I don't know whether the result is correct or not.

Comment: I did, it isn't marshalling over my data properly in that case either.   I was thinking it is due to some array handling at some leaf nodes.   Seems to drop a lot of XML on the floor.  

I double checked that my structs align with the XML structure but I could be missing something foundational about how golang marshalling works (as I am new to it).

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what data was exactly missing, which xml element wasn't unmarshaled into which field? I'm asking because some of your structs actually do not align with the xml, they don't have as many fields as the corresponding xml has children elements.

Comment: ... for example your Lap struct has 3 fields, but the Lap element has more than 3 immediate children elements.

Comment: Yes, apologies....

All of the "trackpoint" data appears to be missing.   I hypothesize this is due to the fact that it is an array and was going to write a custom marshaller to handle the "Track" element.

Comment: The `encoding/xml` package can handle slices just fine and your Trackpoint seems to me to be unmarshaled correctly, see here: https://play.golang.org/p/DF3WSlCOEpb (I'm printing the result as indented json for easier reading)

Comment: Hmm, you are right!   I was looping my trackpoints incorrectly (DOH!).  Now I am confused as to whether I had an issue at all.  

Will try to uncomment my custom marshalers to handle certain data structure conversion (e.g. time formats).

Comment: Also note that a the fields missing from Lap struct are present in your Track struct, so they end up empty because their corresponding xml elements are in the Lap element, not the Track element.

Comment: .... your Lap and Track structs should look more like this: https://play.golang.org/p/DeNQzs9Gr21

Comment: You are right.    I really appreciate your help!   This unblocked me a lot.   Thank you!